# What should be my gitignore with Microsoft Fakes?

Tags: gitignore, microsoft-fakes

I'm using Microsoft Fakes and Git.  There are files in FakesAssemblies which change all the time (.fakes.dll, .fakesconfig, .messages, .xml).  Which of these can I exclude in my gitignore.  If I exlude everything, my build server blows up saying it can't find the files.

Comment: In order to use Microsoft Fakes, the build server must use the Visual Studio Test Runner rather than MSTest. Generally, you should only be including the .fakes files, and letting the fakes be generated at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the items in the FakesAssemblies subfolder would be regenerated on rebuild so all of those can be ignored out.

The Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes is definitely needed.

Your csproj would have references to the .fakes files in the Fakes subfolder which are also required.

A simple way to verify if this is true is just delete the FakesAssemblies subfolder and rebuild.

Comment: This doesn't seem accurate for VS 2015. I deleted my FakeAssemblies subfolder, cleaned, rebuilt; no new subfolder. It's trivial to regen them but there seems no reason to delete them; just ignore them.